# Different output from mks-integrity xmlapi

Tags: java, mks-integrity

I just want to see if somebody else had the same experience with the **mksapi.jar** using java in comparison to the command line. Running on windows.

My problem is that using the option `--xmlapi` with the CLI or using `com.mks.connect.AbstractCmdRunner.executeWithXML(String[] cmd)` with the java API gives different output for the node *Response//WorkItems//WorkItem//Field//Value*

While the CLI has an additional node *TokenValue* containing the value of the "Value", the java API gives the value as part of the *Value* node.

Example:

```
<Field name="projectType">
    <Value dataType="string">
      <TokenValue>Variant</TokenValue>
    </Value>
</Field>
```

vs.

```
<Field name="projectType">
    <Value dataType="string">Variant</Value>
</Field>
```

I wonder if one of you has an explanation - or even better a solution to align both outputs to whatever version.

This example is part of result from `si sandboxinfo --xmlapi`

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the two provide the same results.

The --xmlapi option is an unpublished option, so it's unsupported.

**Disclosure:**  I work for PTC Integrity Technical Support.